# Can I solve x on this way? or is there a mistake I made or is the question wrong?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos3x\sin2x=\cos3x$$
Can I just pull $\cos3x$ out of both sides and continue with $\sin2x=0$ which leaves us with $2x=0$?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Under what conditions are you allowed to *just pull* $\cos(3x)$ *out* ?

Comment: Try bringing $\cos{3x}$ over to the left hand side and factorizing it. $\cos{3x}(\sin{2x}-1)=0$. Where would you go from here?

Comment: First, what if $\cos 3x=0$? Second, if not, and you "pull out", you get $\sin 2x=1$.

Comment: Yes. Provided 1) you take care to handle the case $\cos 3x=0$ separately and 2) you don't mistakenly simplify the RHS to $0$ but to $1$.

Comment: If you "pull"  2 out of 2b =2 do you get b = 0?  Or something else.  Hint you are pulling something out of a multiplication product, not out of addition sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$
\cos(3x) \sin(2x) = \cos(3x) \iff \\
\cos(3x) (\sin(2x) - 1) = 0 \iff \\
\cos(3x) = 0 \vee (\sin(2x) - 1) = 0 \iff \\
\cos(3x) = 0 \vee \sin(2x) = 1 \iff \\
3x = \frac{\pi}{2} + k \pi \vee 2x = \frac{\pi}{2} + m 2\pi \iff \\
x = \frac{\pi}{6} + k \frac{\pi} 3 \vee x = \frac{\pi}{4} + m \pi
$$
for arbitrary $k, m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks you very much! ( Thanks everyone ) I seem to get it now, but I've got one last question on your answer. Isn't it more like this below for the cos(3x) part. cos(3x) = 0 -> 3x = π/2 + mπ

Comment: You are correct, I fixed the result. Good sign, you noticed it. There was a second mistake: For $\cos x$, $\sin x$ the $0$ repeat with period $\pi$ the $1$ with period $2\pi$.

Answer (score -1):

$\cos 3x \sin 2x=\cos 3x\implies \cos 3x=0$ or $\sin 2x=1$

The rest you can solve.$0/0$ is undefined.Keep that in mind.

If any bound on $x$ is given, then answer it appropriately.

Comment: Why the downvote?